# FormData constructor fails to get form data

Tags: javascript, gmail-api, forms, form-data, html-input

I am attempting to capture data from an hmtl form, pass it through a websafe btoa, then send that as a gmail. I'm capturing the form, passing it through the FormData constructor as specified in the MDN docs and getting useless output. What am I doing wrong?

[image: console.logs]
[image: howtheformappears]

The form data object being passed in looks like this. Which is the 'useless output' I am describing.
[image: incorrect form data being passed]

Here is the code that generates these logs...

```
console.log(['got form', form]);

var builtForm = new FormData(form);

console.log(['builtForm', builtForm]);

var testFormObj = window.btoa(builtForm).replace(/\+/g, '-').replace(/\//g, '_');

console.log(testFormObj);
```

Happy to elaborate further on this if necessary. Feel like I'm missing something fundamental and just not catching it. Posting it here to get a second pair of eyes on it. Thank you for your time. **No jQuery or other libraries please.**

Answer (score 0):

The `FormData` object is designed to be passed to the `send` method of an `XMLHttpRequest` object.

It isn't designed to allow you to convert that data to a string by casting it.

Comment: Interesting so because I need to convert the data of the form to a websafe base64 string it's probably best to not use the FormData constructor with this form. Instead use techniques more suited to the task of converting the string properly. Thank you very much.